# Swift - Scroll in Horizontal CollectionView stopped working inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Here's a tricky one...

I have a ScrollView inside of a View Controller with multiple CollectionViews inside.  The CollectionViews are setup for profile photos for horizontal scrolling.

I want the ScrollView to scroll Vertical, but not Horizontal.  I used the following code to do this with the ScrollView:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }

    if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

This works as expected, and I used UIScrollViewDelegate and set the ScrollView as:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Now the tricky part... the CollectionViews no longer scroll horizontally.   I'm assuming that is because the parent ScrollView is taking over the view, and/or the code above is also preventing the horizontal scroll in the CollectionViews.

Anyone have some ideas on how I an achieve what I am looking to?

Cheers,
Aaron

Comment: To follow-up, when I comment out the code, the scrolls work on the CollectionViews again as expected.  However, the ScrollView also scrolls horizontal and vertical - when I only want the ScrollView to scroll vertical and the CollectionViews held inside to scroll horizontal.

Comment: Have you try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your scrollViewDidScroll method

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == self.scrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
        }

        if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Because collectionView also have delegate of scrollView.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `UICollectionView` instead of `UIScrollView` in your case. Seems like your horizontally scrolling collections of images are pretty similar, thus it would be more logically to represent each as a prototype cell of the high-level parent `UICollectionView`. This will also fix your scrolling issues in a natural way =)

More precisely, you will have a **parent** `UICollectionView` with the Scroll direction set to Vertical, owning a `UICollectionViewCell` with the inner **child** `UICollectionView` having the Scroll direction set to Horizontal.

Here is the example how you can do this using the storyboard (look at the second prototype cell):

[image]

In your case, you will just need to fill the child `UICollectionView` with the images instead of the labels, which were used in my example.

Hope, this will help you. Good luck!